# Long functions in OCaml without where clauses

Tags: ocaml, idioms

What is the idiomatic way to write the following code in OCaml, with better readability?

```
let big_function arg =
    let big_helper_fn acc = function
      | p -> ...
      ...
      ...
      ...     foo(arg)
      ...
      ...
      | _ -> ...
    in
    let small_helper_1 a b = 
    ...
    ...
    in
    let small_helper_2 a b =
    ...
    ...
    in

    fold big_function default_acc
    %> small_helper_1 aa1
    %> small_helper_2 aa2
```

Hoisting the inner functions outside may be undesirable for two reasons:

- One may need to pass several arguments explicitly instead of direct access (shown with `foo(arg)` above). This would become cumbersome if there are more arguments, say `big_function` takes in 3 arguments, `big_helper_fn` uses all of them and the accumulator is a tuple of 3 elements too.
- The helper functions become unnecessarily visible in a larger scope than needed. They might be distracting when one is simply skimming the modules because of the same indentation depth with the important `big_function`.

If OCaml had a first class `where` clause this wouldn't be a problem. I did find a [PPX](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/ppx_where/) and another [Github repo](https://github.com/hausdorff/ocaml-where) for this though.

Please provide a reference to a book/style guide/official documentation/name of a large project which follows the method suggested in your answer.

Edit: The trouble I'm having with this code example is that readability is impaired as the actual definition of `big_function` is separated by a lot from the original `let big_function ...` statement at the top. So I'm looking for a more readable idiomatic alternative.

Comment: what does the (%>) operator do?

Comment: @user3240588 , it composes functions from left to right (instead of the usual right to left).

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Your code is already valid in OCaml and fairly idiomatic. A "where" clause would only reverse the order of declaration (which is highly non-idiomatic, in OCaml).

Comment: @Drup I didn't know that this was considered idiomatic in Ocaml (when I asked the question) as it didn't seem very readable to me. I will add the readability part to the question.

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to learn to live with that. Either you lift the declaration out or you keep it inside, with the various downside. Note that `where` clauses are not perfect either: the definition is *after* the use, which is quite annoying to read for many people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks already very OCamlish.  Many large projects are written in such a way: see OCaml compiler implementation itself.  I like `where` in Haskell, but personally I am against arbitrary `where` in non pure language since it may make the ordering of side effects very confusing, which may result into bugs very hard to fix.  Restricting definitions of `where` only to non expansive expressions would be ok but I am not sure the PPX you mention performs such a check or not.

I have never done this, but you could put the "main" task first by using `let rec`:

```
let big_function arg =
  let rec go () =
    fold big_helper_fn default_acc
    %> small_helper_1 aa1
    %> small_helper_2 aa2
  and big_helper_fn acc = function
    ..
  and small_helper_1 a b = 
    ..
  and small_helper_2 a b =
    ..
  in
  go ()
```

Or, you could use a local module:

```
module BigFunctionHelpers(A : sig val arg : t end) = struct
  open A

  let big_helper_fn acc = function ... foo(arg) ...

  let small_helper_1 a b = ...

  let small_helper_2 a b = ...
end

let big_function arg = 
  let module H = BigFunctionHelpers(struct let arg = arg end) in
  let open H in
  fold big_helper_fn default_acc
  %> small_helper_1 aa1
  %> small_helper_2 aa2
```

I do this sometimes when extracting local definitions with many parameters from the parent function.

Comment: The reason I asked this is because the code I've written seems a bit difficult to read, as the actual definition of `big_function` is separated a lot from original `let in` statement. Your second solution seems good, but again it is not as syntactically light-weight as `where`.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without knowing what's going on in the helper functions, but generally speaking you can extract them as top-level functions. This has several advantages:

- it is easier to read
- it reduces the number of variables in scope at every point, reducing risks of referring to the wrong variable (can happen with folds/accumulators)
- it makes it possible to test inner functions

There are some disadvantages as well, as you said:

- there will be more toplevel functions, so there can be naming conflicts (you can use a module to help with that)
- you need to pass more variables explicitly instead of by closures. I'd say that this is an advantage, as this makes coupling more obvious. This is an opportunity to pass less data around (say, a field instead of the whole record).

Comment: The point about testing is useful; I hadn't thought of that. I'm not sure about the second advantage though; if you as passing arguments implicitly through the parent scope anyways, it doesn't really matter. OTOH, if the outer functions arguments aren't being used directly, then I agree it's better to move the smaller ones out.